# TapeEquilibrium O(N*N)

Tags: time-complexity

Can somebody please explain to me why I'm getting O(N*N) complexity on this code? I can't see it.
Bellow is my python code for this Codility problem:

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. Array A
>   represents numbers on a tape.
>       Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ...,
>   A[N − 1].
>
> The difference between the two parts is the value of: |(A[0] + A[1] +
>   ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|
>        In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the first part and the sum of the second part. For example, consider
>   array A such that:
>          A[0] = 3
>          A[1] = 1
>          A[2] = 2
>          A[3] = 4
>          A[4] = 3 We can split this tape in four places:
>
> ```
>  P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7
>  P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5
>  P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1
>  P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
>   Write a function:
>
> def solution(A)
>
>   that, given a non-empty array A of N integers, returns the minimal difference that can be achieved.
> ```

My Code in Python

```
def solution(A):
    sum_array = []
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        sum_array.append(abs(sum(A) - 2*sum(A[i:N])))
    return min(sum_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating a sum of an array has time complexity of O(N). This is because you need to access each array element.
Since you have a loop of N that on each iteration executes sum(A), time complexity of your program is O(N*N)